# Getting the url run by PDO when NOT using bindparam?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

For many queries, it's faster and easier to just use the question-mark notation for a query. There are various guides and posts about getting the final run query by extending PDO, but I never see one that works when using the question-mark notation. Can this be done? I'm running a query that appears by all accounts to work, but it's not returning results in the actual PDO code for some reason. What does it take to actually get the EXACT final query that PDO is running so I can see where the error is?

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT fromID,toID,m_key FROM messages WHERE (fromID = ? AND toID IN (?)) OR (toID = ? AND fromID IN (?)) AND message LIKE 'addfriend'");
$sth->execute(array($_SESSION['userID'],$include,$_SESSION['userID'],$include));
```

Comment: If emulate prepares is `false` that *is* the final query sent to mysql.

Comment: It's not that it's "faster and easier" but that it's safer and cleaner.

Comment: you can see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with the use of the `?` placeholder, but the fact that you try to bind a single variable to represent a list of variables in the `in` operator. You have to provide as many `?` placeholders in the `in` operator separated by commas as the number of parameters you want to have there and you need to bind to each placeholder separately.

```
...fromID IN (?, ?, ?, ..., ?)...
```

Comment: Assuming `$include` is actually list of values, which... who knows?

Comment: Pray, tell me, what else would it be?

Comment: It could be literally anything; a string containing comma separated values, a single value, an object, an array, null. I don't see it being defined anywhere.

Comment: The php data type is not indicated, however, the `in` sql operator expects a list of parameters separated by comma. The OP has a single `?` placeholder there. Technically, `in` works with one parameter, but that does not make too much sense. The most logical assumption is that the OP tries to bind a list of parameters, but all of them go into a single variable. Since the OP only complains about no records being returned, the php data type can't really be array or object, otherwise a php error would have been raised.

Comment: I realized that after some searching, though thank you for clarifying. That said, I can't accept your answer because what I'm looking for specifically is how to get the query that PDO is using.

Comment: Turn on the mysql query log, run the prepared statement and check the query log for the final query. With prepared statements the query and the parameters are sent separately to the server, PDO cannot show you the full query with the parameters interpolated into it. Just do not forget to turn off the query log afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The below method will help you to substitute the value ($params) against `?` or `:param` placeholder. So that we can see the exact query to be executed.

Note: It is useful only for development debugging purpose.

```
   public static function interpolateQuery($query, $params) {
        $keys = array();
        $values = $params;

        # build a regular expression for each parameter
        foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
            if (is_string($key)) {
                $keys[] = '/:'.$key.'/';
            } else {
                $keys[] = '/[?]/';
            }

            if (is_array($value))
                $values[$key] = implode(',', $value);

            if (is_null($value))
                $values[$key] = 'NULL';
        }
        // Walk the array to see if we can add single-quotes to strings
        array_walk($values, create_function('&$v, $k', 'if (!is_numeric($v) && $v!="NULL") $v = "\'".$v."\'";'));

        $query = preg_replace($keys, $values, $query, 1, $count);

        return $query;
    }
```

Comment: Is there really no way for the PDO to return the exact and final query that it creates and sends to the DB? Must it always be emulated?

Comment: @not_a_generic_user : Yes i think. I also surfed a lot and i can't find thats why i used this method to get final query to be executed.